# Elasticsearch: Improve research using special field as P.K. into the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, templates, elasticsearch

The following is a templeate in ElasticSearch, my question is, if there is a way to promote one of these fields, for example `timeStamp`, as primary key to help the research during the query; like it happens on database usually.

```
  {
  "order": 0,
  "template": "simsamples-*",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "ProbeSamples": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "index": "no",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "timeStamp": {
          "format": "epoch_second",
          "type": "date"
        },
        "temperatures": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "id": {
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no primary key in elasticsearch. Every document automatically has an `_id` field, which is a kind of a primary key because it is a unique identifier.

Elasticsearch is creating indices for every field, so there is no need to specify one as primary key.

Comment: The question is this, how to create/optimize the template in Elasticsearch to get a 
 faster response? if there is.

Comment: I'm using an old version of ES: 2.4.5. Right now, reading regarding mapping and keyword, are they concerned with my original question, optimize the template field research?